# What are the possible bounds on the norm of a vector with respect to positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Suppose we have a vector $\mathbf{x}\in \mathcal{X} \subset  \mathbb{R}^d$, and $H$ is a PD matrix. Also, we know that $S=\max_{x\in \mathcal{X}}||x||$. I am wondering if it is possible to find some bounds on $||x||_{H}$ and $||x||_{H^{-1}}$?

I have define $S$ as $S=\max_{x\in \mathcal{X}}||x||$. I am wondering if there is any relation between $S$ and matrices $H$ and $H^{-1}$ when we use the norm with respect to these matrices?

Comment: Since $\|x\|_H=\|H^{1/2}x\|\le\|H^{1/2}\|\|x\|=\|H\|^{1/2}\|x\|$, an obvious upper bound of $\max_{x\in\mathcal X}\|x\|_H$ is $\|H\|^{1/2}S$. Similarly, $\max_{x\in\mathcal X}\|x\|_{H^{-1}}\le\|H^{-1}\|^{1/2}S$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it also possible to find bounds on $||H^{-1}||^{1/2}$ based on its eigenvalues?

Comment: If $H$ is positive definite, $\|H^{-1}\|^{1/2}=\lambda_\min(H)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Suppose we have $H=\lambda I +\sum_{s=1}^{t}x_s x_s^T$. How is it possible to prove that $ ||\lambda x||_{H^{-1}} \le \sqrt{\lambda} S$? Thanks

Comment: Also, is it possible to find bounds when $H=\lambda I + \sum_{s=1}^{t}\sigma_s x_s x_s^T$ and $\sigma_s >0$?

Comment: Since $H\succeq\lambda I$, we have $H^{-1}\preceq\lambda^{-1}I$. Therefore $\max_{x\in\mathcal X}\|\lambda x\|_{H^{-1}}\le\lambda\|H^{-1}\|^{1/2}S\le\lambda\|\lambda^{-1}I\|^{1/2}S=\sqrt{\lambda}S$.

Comment: Thank you so much.